# Regex for password strength not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to show password strength while creating new user account so I have following criteria

- less than 8 characters -> Too short
- 8 to 15 characters only alphabets(Upper and lower) or only numeric -> Weak
- 8 to 15 characters alphabets(Upper and lower) and at least one number -> Moderate
- 8 to 15 characters alphabets(Upper and lower) and at least one number and at least one special character -> strong

And I am trying with the following regex in my javascript

```
/^.{1,7}$/, //Too Short
/^([a-zA-Z]{8,15})$/, //Weak
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,15}$/, //Moderate
/^([a-zA-Z0-9@\!_#\$\^%&*()+=\-[]\\\';,\.\/\{\}\|\":<>\? ]{8,15})$/] //Strong
```

But they are not working. Please help me with above regex.

Comment: Define `not working`?

Comment: not getting validated

Comment: Maybe you should pick a stronger password

Answer (score 3):

might be easier to reason about and provide feedback to users if you create one regex per "rule".

```
var rules = [
    [/[a-z]/,     'must include lower case letter'],
    [/[A-Z]/,     'must include upper case letter'],
    [/\d/,        'must include number'],
    [/[^\w\d]/,   'must include punctuation character'],
    [/^.{8,15}$/, 'must be 8 to 15 digits'],
    [/(.)\1+/,    'characters cannot be repeated'] ];
```

Comment: And there's part of the answer right there.  @user3275493, this is how you would start to check against multiple classes and check that every class matches.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your patters.  You seem to be trying to test for week ones and then test for a strong password.  Your pattern is using a character class, however.  So that means any of the provided characters will work.  A "strong" password could theoretically be "aaaaaaaa" because it is at least 8 characters long and fits the `a-z` part of your character class.  You also have a syntax error.  Your sequence ends `]{8,15})$/]` where it looks like you mean `]{8,15})$/`.  another syntax error is that you have unescaped `[]` in a character class.  They need to be `\[\]`.

Finally, I would suggest reading up on "[Character Escapes](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)".  It will simplify your patterns significantly.  for instance you could swap out `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `_` with `\w` (word characters) in your character class.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have very less idea on regex. So it would be helpful if you could help me with proper regex for above criteria.

Comment: @user3275493 Unfortunately I can't at the moment (I can only interject here and there because I'm doing so from work).  I suggest going over the page I linked and trying to understand how the regex works.  Then break each of the problems into parts and, after trying it yourself, ask for help on those specific topics.  To get you started, here is one question you might search for (or if you can't find it, you can start a new question): "How do I use multiple character classes in a regex pattern?" or "How do I check that every character class is used in a regex pattern?"

Answer (score 0):

you would have to run it through a series of checks:

`^.{1,7}$` too short

`^[a-zA-Z]{8,15}$` or `^\d{8,15}$` weak

`^[a-zA-Z\d]{8,15}$` moderate

`^[a-zA-Z\d\W]{8,15}$` strong